# AdMob test Ad displays but has a download button. Anyone know why it is happing

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, admob, ads

[image: Test AD Image]

I am getting a download button displaying in the middle of my test ad. The test ad displays but then when I click on it the download button pops up and I need to click it in order to open the ad link. Anyone know why it is happening.

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
 interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
 let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
 interstitial.delegate = self
 interstitial.load(GADRequest())
 return interstitial
}

 // Run Code here that you want after Ad closes like a restart game func.

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {

 interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()

 countStartPressed = 0
 GameHandler.sharedInstance.startPressed = countStartPressed
 restart()
}


// Update the countStartPressed here and save it to gameData
// CountStartPressed is the number of time the start game button is pressed in the gameOverScene

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

 countStartPressed = GameHandler.sharedInstance.startPressed

 if countStartPressed == 1 {

   if (self.interstitial.isReady) {

     self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController (self.view?.window!.rootViewController)!)

   } else {

       print("Ad wasn't ready")

   }
 } 
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this is expected behavior. Apple has stopped allowing ads to directly open in AppStore.

Comment: This is in the simulator. When I run some of my practice projects they seem to work fine and go to the AdMob webpage. But this one I have to click download and then it opens up the AdMob webpage.

Comment: Is this a problem only on the simulator? And on actual device it always redirects?

Comment: I haven't tried on actual device. I don't have access to one yet.

Comment: I changed the simulator to an iPad and it works. I think the problem was with the simulator because it seems to work fine know. I tried the other simulators and only the iPhone 11 Pro max simulator seems to have the issue.

Comment: Interesting. Can you add all these details to the question? Also, can you try testing it on an actual 11 Pro Max if possible?